# what is the correct inputs for cv.basicfacerecognizer

Tags: matlab, opencv

I am trying to provided sample code for cv.facerecognition in mexopencv - Matlab, but i am getting an error in cv.facerecognition which says

Undefined function or variable 'BasicFaceRecognizer_'.

```
Error in cv.BasicFaceRecognizer (line 131)
            this.id = BasicFaceRecognizer_(0, 'new', ftype, varargin{:});
```

I couldn't find any solution for  that, i appreciate your support

thanks

Comment: Please include the link to what you're following/using. Apparently `BasicFaceRecognizer_` is not in your path. Just guessing: you may need to use `mex` as well.

Comment: actually, I am using mex, and I have done the configuration 

and using this sample  code 
https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/blob/master/opencv_contrib/samples/facerec_demo.m